# Setting variables from array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, variables

I was processing some data that I got while doing a project and coded this:

```py
# Parse data from txt file
data = numpy.loadtxt(inFileName + '.txt', skiprows=3)
freq = data[:, 0]   # Mirror Frequency (Hz)
sdfreq = data[:, 1] # σ Frequency (Hz)
dist = data[:, 2]   # ∆X (m)
sddist = data[:, 3] # σ ∆X (m)
```

And I realized that the last 4 lines look repetitive and I was obviously not going to repeat doing that if I had 1000 more data parameters. I could obviously parse it into a dictionary but that would force me to call `dataset['freq'][0]` instead of simply `freq[0]`. I could also parse it into an object and call `dataset.freq[0]`, which would be better. But, is there a way I can compact the code and still have the ability to use `freq[0]` (without using `exec()`)?

Comment: If it were a tuple you could do `freq, sdfreq, dist, sddist = data`. I'm not sure what the numpy equivalent is.

Comment: Maybe `freq, sdfreq, dist, sddist = data[:]`

Comment: Why do you need to assign these columns to variables?  I can see doing that for 4 columns, but 1000?  There's nothing particularly wrong with those 4 lines.  The unpacking suggested by others may be handy, but isn't necessarily clearer.

Comment: With `dtype` and `names` is possible to get a structured array, for which you could access fields by name, e.g. `data['freq']` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use  `unpack=True`:

```
import numpy

data = numpy.loadtxt(inFileName + '.txt', skiprows=3 , unpack=True )
[freq, sdfreq, dist, sddist] = data

print(freq, sdfreq, dist, sddist)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand every aspect of your problem but I think you are on the right track. Is this of some help to you?

```py
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])

def assign(data):
    result = []

    for i in range(data.shape[1]):
        result.append(list(data[:,i]))

    return result

freq, sdfreq, dist, sddist = assign(data)
```

or shorter:

```py
freq, sdfreq, dist, sddist = [list(data[:,i]) for i in range(data.shape[1])]
```

**Explanation:**

Instead of parsing the data into a dictionary you can assign the columns to individual variables in one step:

For each column ('i in range(data.shape[1](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/user/basics.rec.html))') return the column 'data[:,i]' as you did manually.

Cave: you need to keep track of column indeces, if your dataset changes you need to insert a new variable at the exact position. Perhaps a [structured table](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/user/basics.rec.html) or [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/03_subset_data.html#min-tut-03-subset) might be helpful in the long run (especially when it comes to 1000+ columns).

Comment: That is what I wanted, but Daniil's answer is more adequate for my problem.